# Issue With Image Rendereing

Tags: xna, c#, xna-4.0, windows-phone-7

I'm pretty New to the XNA Side of things,

I have built in PhotoShop a Set of frame by Frame images side by side to go through an animation class to display them frame by frame.

With this my images will not show up properly, they look more like a film reel.

Were could I Ggt good information on images for animation for XNA?

Comment: wow - this is the edited version...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at [Sprite Sheet Sample](http://create.msdn.com/en-US/education/catalog/sample/sprite_sheet) at App Hub.

Comment: Is this used in large numbers for Games?

Comment: Yes, sprite sheets/sprite atlas are widely used on videogames. They allow you to pack a bunch of images into a single file, thus reducing loading times (I/O operations are expensive on some hardware) and adding an extra layer of abstraction to easily access the resources.

Comment: Alright, thank you! Appreciate taking the time to help me! :)